# Quarkus GraphQL: How to change the default endpoint?

Tags: graphql, java-ee-6, quarkus, smallrye

I am using the dependency as shown below in a Quarkus application. Default the endpoint is `/graphql`. But since I am running this application in a k8s environment behind a ingress, this is not ideal. Anyone has an idea how to change this default endpoint to something like: `/<service-name>/graphql`?

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.smallrye</groupId>
  <artifactId>smallrye-graphql-servlet</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the SmallRye GraphQL extension, you can control the endpoint path using `application.properties`:

```
quarkus.smallrye-graphql.root-path=/my-path-to-graphql
```

You can also use variables (with `${variableName}` syntax) in the value, so you can inject your service name there.

But to be using that extension you need to adjust the dependency to

```
   <dependency>
      <groupId>io.quarkus</groupId>
      <artifactId>quarkus-smallrye-graphql</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Note that it's only available since Quarkus 1.5.0.